# Ionic start give me an error in MacOS Mojave

Tags: node.js, macos, ionic-framework

Operating system: MacOS Mojave 10.14.2

ionic: 4.10.3
node: 10.15.2
npm: 6.4.1

When I am trying to create a new project the ionic or npm fails:

when giving the command:

sudo ionic start testApp blank --type=ionic-angular

```
> node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall /Users/international/Public/testApp/node_modules/node-sass

> node scripts/build.js



Building: /usr/local/bin/node /Users/international/Public/testApp/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=

gyp info it worked if it ends with ok

gyp verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',

gyp verb cli   '/Users/international/Public/testApp/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',

gyp verb cli   'rebuild',

gyp verb cli   '--verbose',

gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',

gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',

gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',

gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]

gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0

gyp info using node@10.15.2 | darwin | x64

gyp verb command rebuild []

gyp verb command clean []

gyp verb clean removing "build" directory

gyp verb command configure []

gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "/usr/bin/python2.7" in the PATH

gyp verb `which` succeeded /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python2.7

gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python2.7 -c "import sys; print "2.7.10

gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j

gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 10.15.2

gyp verb command install [ '10.15.2' ]

gyp verb install input version string "10.15.2"

gyp verb install installing version: 10.15.2

gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed

gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"

gyp verb got "installVersion" 9

gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9

gyp verb install version is good

gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 10.15.2

gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /Users/international/Public/testApp/node_modules/node-sass/build

gyp ERR! configure error 

gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/international/Public/testApp/node_modules/node-sass/build'

gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0

gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/international/Public/testApp/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="

gyp ERR! cwd /Users/international/Public/testApp/node_modules/node-sass

gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.2

gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0

gyp ERR! not ok 

Build failed with error code: 1

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/fsevents):

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 install: `node install`

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1



npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.



npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /Users/international/.npm/_logs/2019-03-05T09_26_51_725Z-debug.log

[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.



        npm i exited with exit code 1.
```

Somewhere you will find "permission denied" as an error but in my command I used sudo as a prefix.

I have no clue what is happened and I tried many hours to find a solution to this. Also I am new user on MacOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the ownership of the `node_modules` folder.

To change the permissions for the folder execute the following in the terminal:

```
sudo chown -R root:YOUR_USERNAME /Users/international/Public/testApp/node_modules/

sudo chmod -R 775 /Users/international/Public/testApp/node_modules/
```

If that doesn't work you can recursively set the permissions for your folder as follows:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /Users/international/Public/testApp/
```